# How to run a piece of javascript when you select a dropdown option?

Tags: javascript

I have a select with loads of options. (Code below shortened for sake of example).
I want it to set the value of the input textfield "hoh" to "10" when you click/select all dropdown options, except one, that should set it to 50.

I imagined something like this would work, but its not. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<select>
    <option onselect="document.getElementById('hoh').value = '50'">Hey</option>
    <option onselect="document.getElementById('hoh').value = '10'">Ho</option>
    <option onselect="document.getElementById('hoh').value = '10'">Lo</option>
    ....
</select>

<input type="text" id="hoh" value="10">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<script>
function myFunc(val) {
    if (val == '50') {
        document.getElementById('hoh').value = val;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hoh').value = '10';
    }
}
</script>

<select onchange="myFunc(this.value)">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="50">fifty</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/LH57d/3

Comment: Updated to better match the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `onselect` event refers to selecting (or highlighting) text. To trigger an action when a dropbox selection changes, use the `onchange` event trigger for the `<select>` element.

E.g. Since you didn't already set the value attribute of your option tags.

```
<select id="myselect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="50">Hey</option>
    <option value="10">Ho</option>
    <option value="10">Lo</option>
    ....
</select>
```

and somewhere inside of a `<script>` tag (presumably in your HTML header) you define your javascript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript>

function myFunction() {
   var dropbox = document.getElementById('myselect');
   document.getElementById('hoh').value = dropbox[dropbox.selectedIndex].value;
}

</script>
```

I'm not sure it's wise to repeat the same value among different options in a droplist, but you could expand on this to implement the result other ways, such as if the sole option which will have value `50` is in a certain position, you could compare the `selectedIndex` to that position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var inp = document.getElementById('hoh');
sel.onchange = function(){
    var v = this.value;
    if( v !== '50'){
         v = '10';
    }
    inp.value = v;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add an onchange event trigger to the select, and use the value of an option to show in the textbox

see http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/5g5pg/ here

```
<select onchange="setValue(this, 'hoh')">
    <option>-- select --</option>
    <option value="10">Test</option>
    <option value="50">Test 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="hoh" />
```

with function setValue as

```
function setValue(source, target) {
    var tg = document.getElementById(target);
    if (!tg) {
        alert('No target element found');
        return;
    }
    if (source.selectedIndex <= 0) {
        tg.value = '';
        return;
    }
    var opt = source.options[source.selectedIndex];
    tg.value = opt.value;
}
```